# Are there any different endings to Emily Is Away?

Tags: emily-is-away

I've played the game a few different ways, and so far have not had a lot of variation in the ending.

> Frankly, I'm starting to believe it's little more than a "friend-zone simulator".

Is there any way to bring the game to a conclusion that's substantially different, particularly with regards to the Player/Emily relationship?

Answer (score 4):

I have played the game several times and searched for several different playthroughs on YouTube. As far as I can tell, there is no other way the game can end: the player's relationship with Emily is always in tatters by the time the two of them leave university. The form of this disintegration changes with each ending: for example, in one ending, Emily says that she's back together with Brad and the player can no longer talk to her; in another ending, Emily says that she can't talk to the player because she has homework to do. Yet it will always happen. There is no happy ending to this game, no matter what you do.

Comment: the second one can be the best ending depending on how you performed in chapter 3 I guess

Answer (score 2):

Those are the endings in Emily is away

**Awkward ending**

If you decide to talk to Emily in chapter 4, where she talks to you about the events that happened during her visit, in chapter 5, you will have the standard ending like she got back with Brad/Travis (depending on if you went to the party in chapter 1 or not) and if you try to drag on the conversation, you will end with three goodbyes in the choice.

This ending is when you invest a lot into her and obviously would be seen as a bad ending.

**Best ending**

Then, you wanna be a jerk and decide to take revenge on her. You want to abuse her at her most vulnerable moment, it means at chapter 3, when she suggests to visit you. Let her come (not only as friends), be a gentleman and tell her that you have alcohol. Then, on chapter 4, you don't talk to her! You can imagine what happened during your visit and you're kinda happy with Emma, don't let that drama queen turn your head around, make an excuse or something.
And finally, on chapter 5, when you try to talk to her, she'll just make the same excuse to you and the game ends.

So, to sum up, you scored something with Emily, you are with Emma, game over, best ending.

Comment: so emily is a bitch either way. and i was like is this going to be a love story in the making. sheesh.

Comment: better luck with the second game
also, there's a third on the way I think

Answer (score -1):

Yea there is a good ending with Em i got it the second playthrouh but just 0.3% get this ending. I didn't do much differently than the first time :)

[image]

Comment: Well what is this "good" ending and how did you get it?

Comment: And does it differ from the ending in the other answer?